# How to implement badge in firebase notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm making android application letters to my office, and I've been using the notification of the firebase. So I want to add badges in my apps when I get the notification.

My question is how to add badges on firebase notification?

Thanks.